# ggplot increasing the distance between axis labels and axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've exhausted the documentation and previous questions on Stackoverflow but I can't seem to overcome this simple challenge.

```
df <- read_csv("book1.csv")

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = xData, y = yData, color = colorData)) +
  geom_point(aes(text = paste("Contact:", Contact, "Number:", Number,sep="\n")), size = 1) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=rel(0.6))) +
  facet_wrap(~ colorData, nrow = 4, ncol = 2) +
  xlim(0, 10) +   ylim(0, 10) + 
  labs = (x = "\nxData", y = "yData\n") 

ggplotly(p)
```

At the moment, my x and y labels sit on top of the ticks on all facets and I wish to extend the axis labels away from the ticks.

So far I've tried:

```
labs = (x = "\nxData", y = "yData\n")
```

```
xlab("\nxData") + ylab("yData\n")
```

```
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 9, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)))+
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 9, b = 0, l = 0)))
```

```
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5))+
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(hjust=-0.5))
```

```
theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(margin = margin(t = 2, unit = "in")))+
theme(axis.title.y.left = element_text(margin = margin(r = 2, unit = "in")))
```

Nothing seems to work here. Any suggestions welcomed.

EDIT: data in copy-pasteable format:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~xData, ~yData, ~colorData, ~Contact, ~Number,
  3.4,    6.7,   "Dept 1",   "John",    143L,
  4.5,    7.7,   "Dept 2",   "Paul",    353L,
  6.7,    8.7,   "Dept 3",   "Mary",    232L,
  8.9,    9.9,   "Dept 4",  "Steve",    235L,
  3.4,     10,   "Dept 5",   "Bill",    124L,
  5.6,    5.4,   "Dept 6",   "Jess",    421L,
  7.6,    4.5,   "Dept 7",  "Peter",    212L
)
```

So it appears this may be an issue caused when calling `ggploty(p)` for an interactive plot but not for a regular plot.

Comment: You probably need the `axis.title.x.bottom` and `axis.title.y.left` theme arguments. See discussion: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4343

Comment: @teunbrand wonderful I was thinking the same ... weird... ;)

Comment: haha, well at least now you know you're not the only one confused by this! :D

Comment: @teunbrand Thank you for the reply. I took a look at the link you provided and added `scale_x_continuous(position = "bottom") + theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(margin = margin(b = 1, unit = "in")))` to no luck! Not sure whats going on here. Edit: added a line of code.

Comment: Also `theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(margin = margin(t = 1, unit = "in")))` doesn't work?

Comment: @teunbrand No luck either with that unfortunately. It's a mystery to me at this point.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example for us to play with, i.e. include some of the data (or dummy data)? Its becoming clear that looking at the code an guessing what goes wrong isn't going to solve this.

Comment: erm - have you tried changing `axis.text.x` instead?

Comment: @teunbrand https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Avo9DQQHjt-JzSsQUYeQURr5GWLLIHjL/view?usp=sharing I can give a very basic example of the data here

Comment: @tjebo No luck!

Comment: I think you might have misspelled the `labs(x = "\nxData", y = "yData\n")` line, and the point geom doesn't have a `text` aesthetic, but other than that @tjebo's suggestion works with the code/data you've provided as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yeah I agree that @tjebo 's suggestion does work indeed. I'll just add to that to have some tooltips on hover and other such customisations. Thanks all for the help. I'm still not entirely sure why this happened but it seems to be resolved.

Comment: You know what it is, printing a static plot `p` is fine, but sending it to `ggplotly(p)` is where the problem arises. @teunbrand

Comment: Right that seems to be a plotly issue then. Seeing as this was relevant to finding the problem, you might consider including that piece of information in the question.

Comment: @teunbrand done. And also very annoying. Ill flag it as an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just too long for a comment - no real answer.

Here to show how this could look like.

Try to run this code in your session and see if you have the same result. If not, then you have some weird global settings set. I'd then restart R, start a new session, and possibly also update all your packages.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) +
  facet_wrap(~ carb, nrow = 4, ncol = 2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 1, unit = "in")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for that detailed comment. I'll try built out from your code and see where the problem arises.