# Edit the space between axis ticks and axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to learn to increase the space between the `axis.ticks` and the axis labels.

Here is an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=bill_length_mm,bill_depth_mm, fill=species), size=5, shape=21, color="white", alpha=0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1B6CA8","#D78E00","#438A5E" )) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=12), 
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.25, "cm"))
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This is what I want:

[image]

I have tried to use the `axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0,r = 0,b = 2,l = 0, unit="cm")))` **but with this command, I am only moving the title. I only want to move the labels, NOT the title!**

Comment: I am not sure why you thought that `margin(t = 0,r = 0,b = 2,l = 0, unit="cm"))` would increase the margin between axis labels and ticks? b = bottom. In your answer, with `margin(5,0,0,0)` you are adding a margin to the top `t`. I think it's better to explicitly name the position where you want to add a margin. Instead of your below code in the answer, you can then use `axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 5))`, because any of those positions t/r/b/l have 0 as a default

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66102618/ggplot-increasing-the-distance-between-axis-labels-and-axis-ticks.

Comment: thats a very good point @tjebo I agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of Philippe Massicotte from the R4DS slack group here is a solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=bill_length_mm,bill_depth_mm, fill=species), size=5, shape=21, color="white", alpha=0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1B6CA8","#D78E00","#438A5E" )) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=12), 
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.25, "cm"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(5,0,0,0)), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,5,0,0)))
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>